# Centrar text Css

Tags: css, reactjs, web

Tengo un versus el cual va lanzando personajes random. De un lado tengo el personaje1 y del otro al personaje2 y en el medio la palabra vs. El problema es que al ser palabras random nunca está centrado el "vs" ya que hay palabras más grande que otras y esta se va rotando mucho y me quedan cosas como estas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que a pesar de cual sea la palabra el "vs" siempre quede centrado aunque los personajes sean diferentes.

```
<p className="tematica__versus">{tematicaRandom.personaje1}
  <span className="tematica__vs">vs</span>
  {tematicaRandom.personaje2}
</p>



.tematica__versus{
        font-size: 80px;
        color: #e1e1e1e1;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-top: 70px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .tematica__vs{
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Si son diferentes... ¿Como estas ordenando esas palabras? Estan cada palabra dentro de un div diferente ?? o las 3 son un div, por que puede que ese sea tu problema para empezar. Recuerda añadir el código de tu desarrollo para ver que sucede.

Comment: Ok, ya edito la publicación

Comment: Recuerda añadir en el post y en las etiquetas el lenguaje en el que estás trabajando. Ahora mismo no se si es php puro o laravel u otra cosa.

Comment: React, ya lo edité

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que haría seria agruparlo dentro de un contenedor flexbox [te dejo este enlace para aprender un poco mas sobre flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
.flebox-container {
  display: flex; /*convertimos en flexbox el contenedor*/
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /*acá le decimos que solo sea de una sola linea*/
  justify-content: space-between; /*aca le decimos que se separen automaticamente el primero a la izquierda de todo, el segundo siempre al medio y el ultimo a la derecha de todo.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flebox-container">
  <p class="personaje1">{tematicaRandom.personaje1}</p>
  <p class="vs">vs</p>
  <p class="personaje2">{tematicaRandom.personaje2}</p>
</div>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Y para ayudarte a conseguir algo más cercano a lo que el OP quiere, bastaría con alinear el personaje1 a la derecha y el personaje2 a la izquierda para que se encuentren en el medio.